# How to grep for a digit after a word and a space in a file and process it in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, grep

For example, a file file.txt containts

Total 60
Maths 20
Physics 15
Chemistry 25
bla bla 10
bla bla bla 15

Now I need to grep Total,Maths,Physics,Chemistry values and check whether total=maths+physics+chemistry or not.
How can I do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
data = {}
File.open("/path/to/data_file", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |l|
        # Split the line around non-white space chars
        # last element in split result will be marks, rest are parts of subject
        *v1, v2 = l.chomp.split(/\W+/)

        # Use subject name as key and marks as value 
        data[v1.join(' ')] = v2.to_i
    end
end

p data
#=> {"Total"=>60, "Maths"=>20, "Physics"=>15, "Chemistry"=>25, 
#    "bla bla"=>10, "bla bla bla"=>15}

# Let's remove the :total from hash, so that we are only left 
# with individual subject's marks
total_marks = data.delete("Total")

# Add total of specific subjects
added_total = data.values_at("Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry").reduce(:+)

# If sum of all subjects needed, un-comment below line
# added_total_all = data.values.reduce(:+)

puts "Total: #{total_marks}, sum of marks: #{added_total}"
#=> Total: 60, sum of marks: 60
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to consider only physics, chemistry and Maths

Comment: That should be easy to incorporate in above code.

Comment: @WandMaker  Above code shows syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '='        *v1, v2 = l.chomp.split(/\W+/)

Comment: I am not understanding this line --> data[v1.join(' ')] = v2.to_i

Comment: @NavaneethCp - Its same as saying `data["Chemistry"] = "25".to_i`.  Also, since you had strings like `"bla bla bla"` - in that case it is same as `data[["bla","bla","bla"].join(' ')] = "15".to_i`.  `join(" ")` concatenates elements of an array with spaces in between, `to_i` converts a string to integer.

Comment: Thanks @WandMaker for the input.